# Write to a file that is already used

Tags: java

i want to write to a File, that is already in use by an other process.

My Question is: is there a way to avoid the FilenotfoundException, and to write to the file although it is in use?

Thank you!

Comment: Whether or not you can write to a file in use by another process isn't really a Java issue, but has to do with the underlying OS.

Comment: Post your code and the exact error message. If the file exists, you  shouldn't encounter a `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Why are you using the same file from two processes? I'm willing to bet there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Oracle docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html), do the following check:

boolean canWrite() - Returns true if a file is writable by the current application; false otherwise.

boolean canRead() - Returns true if a file is readable by the current application; false otherwise.

If you are asking if you can write to the file while it is in use by another application, you might be able to force it, but it depends on the behaviour of the other application.

Comment: Yeah , my question was, if there is a way to force it,but thank you for your answer!

Comment: I have never used this, but [**FileChannel**](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) might be what you need. Here's a pretty [**good example**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/DemonstratesfilelockingandsimplefilereadandwriteoperationsusingjavaniochannelsFileChannel.htm) too.

Answer (score 0):

If the other process acquired a `lock` on the file your application want to use, you have to ensure the application waits for a specific amount of time until the lock gets released. The `locking mechanism` is purely depends up on the other process that uses the `file`. 
You may try something like this

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("test.txt");  
    FileChannel channel = fin.getChannel();  
    FileLock lock = channel.tryLock();  
    if (lock != null) {  
        try {  
            // read the file  
        } finally {  
            lock.release();  
        }  
    } else {  
        // some other process has locked the file for some reason  
    }
```